# Curl: Post Method with Submit Button of the Image Type

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

An external ASPX page has an input text area. To send entered text, there is a submit button of the image type:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ibQGo" id="ctl00_ibQGo" src="../img/go.gif" />
```

This [instruction](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST) explains the use of the type=submit button with a name and value, but in my case this doesn't work.

What should I pass in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in PHP to have this button clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install the [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/httpfox/) addon in FireFox (or an addon with a similar function in case of other web browsers). Open the ASPX page, then press Ctrl+Shift+I and open the **Network** tab. On the ASPX page, enter desired values in the text area and press image button. You will see all GETs and POSTs. See the **Parameters** subtab to find out what parameters should be passed and their values.
Be sure to include __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION values. However, it is not as simple as that. You can adapt [this script](http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/12/screen-scraping-aspnet-application-in.html) for your purposes. It worked for me.